# how to add web application to a Tomcat instance?

Tags: java, tomcat

How can I add a web application to Tomcat instance using java code? I'm having hard time of linking the directory where .war located to the Tomcat.

Comment: Why do you want to do it with Java code? There are several suitable build tools that can do this for you, and even a simple shell script can copy your .war to `tomcat/webapp/`.

Comment: @Kayaman: i am writing embedded web application integration testing.and i want to check if it deploys correctly

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can copy `.war` file to Tomcat's `wars` dir by SFTP using [Jsch library](http://www.jcraft.com/jsch/) for Java. Something like:

```
  JSch jSch = new JSch();
  Session session = jSch.getSession(user, host, 22);
  session.setPassword(password);
  Properties config = new Properties();
  session.setConfig(config);

   session.connect();

   Channel channel = session.openChannel("sftp");
   channel.connect();
   sftp = (ChannelSftp) channel;

   try {

       sftp.cd("/your/tomcat/dir/wars");

       File file = getWarFile();
       sftp.put(new FileInputStream(file), file.getName());

   } catch (SftpException e) {
       e.printStackTrace();
   }
```

Once you have copied your `.war` into Tomcat's war directory, you have to execute the proper remote scripts to restart your Tomcat and your new webapp will be deployed.

You can execute this remote scripts using Jsch, too.